# How do I get HTTP::Proxy to log filter information?

Tags: perl, http, proxy, documentation

I'm having some trouble getting filters working with [HTTP::Proxy](http://search.cpan.org/~book/HTTP-Proxy-0.24/lib/HTTP/Proxy.pm) and I just can't seem to figure out what I should add to the `logmask()` function to get that information.

I've got a log file, that part is fine, logging is happening, but no information about filters, although they're implemented and (sometimes) working.

I've tried

- `logmask(['FILTERS'])`
- `logmask('FILTERS')`
- `logmask(FILTERS)`

and none of those work! What am I missing?

Also, what's all that about the powers of two for the mask? And the constants being exported by `:log`?

I'm rather confused, as you can tell.

EDIT:

going by the advice below, I have the following script:

```
#!/sw/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTTP::Proxy qw( :log );
use HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::tags;
use HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::simple;
open( LOG, '>>', "/Users/ambrose/proxy-log.txt" ) or die "$!";

my $proxy = HTTP::Proxy->new;
$proxy->port(3128);
$proxy->logfh(*LOG);
$proxy->logmask( ALL );

$proxy->push_filter(
    mime     => 'text/html',
    response => HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::tags->new(),
    response => HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::simple->new(
        sub { ${ $_[1] } =~ s!(</?)i>!$1b>!ig }
    )
);

$proxy->start;
```

which doesn't log anything about filters, although the filter is in operation, I can see that italics have been changed to bold, as in the example.

If I change the line:

```
$proxy->logmask( ALL );
```

to

```
$proxy->logmask( FILTERS );
```

nothing gets added to the log file at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that the logging constants are not exported by default, but by the :log tag. They can also be exported one-by-one.

They're symbolic constants, so you want to do `$proxy->logmask( FILTERS )`, but first you need to `use HTTP::Proxy qw(:log)` or `use HTTP::Proxy qw(FILTERS)`.

Or if you don't like namespace pollution you should be able to do `$proxy->logmask( HTTP::Proxy::FILTERS() )`